# Half-circle with a full-circle CSS one element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an element which is a half-circle with a complete circle border. Like this:

[image: half circle]

I have no problem doing it with using 2 elements, but don't fully understand how to do it within one DIV.

Right now all I have is a half circle:

```
.element {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #00a680;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use gradient:

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 15px solid #00a680;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00a680 50%, transparent 0) content-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: this is a super-elegant solution!

Comment: Use 1em padding and border and it'll become same as the picture in OP